# Proving the exponential decay of Green's function for the lattice $-\Delta+p$

Tags: co.combinatorics, estimation-theory, green-function

The Green function $G(x,y) =G(x-y)$ of the discrete Klein-Gordon operator $-\Delta+p$ on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is given by:
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x-y) = \int_{[-\pi,\pi]^{d}}\frac{d^{d}k}{(2\pi)^{d}}\frac{e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}}{\gamma(k)+p} \quad (x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}) \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
where $p>0$, $k\cdot (x-y) := k_{1}(x_{1}-y_{1}) +\cdots+k_{d}(x_{d}-y_{d})$ and:
$$\gamma(k) := 2\sum_{j=1}^{d}(1-\cos(k_{j})). $$

Now, I think I've read somewhere (I don't seem to recall what was the article, sadly) that this function has exponential decay, i.e:
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x-y) \le Ke^{\alpha ||x-y||_{\infty}} \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\alpha$ and $K$ are positive constants and $||x-y||_{\infty} := \text{max}\{|x_{1}-y_{1}|,...,|x_{d}-y_{d}|\}$. I'm trying by myself to prove this result (and I don't think it is very difficult) but my first couple attempts were unsuccessfull. I've tried math stack and nobody helped me either, so I'm starting to doubt my memory and I don't know if this estimate holds. So my question is: does (\ref{2}) hold and, if so, how can I prove it?

Comment: you need $p>0$ for the decay.

Comment: Oh, right! So the decay really holds. Thanks! It's edited already!

Comment: The quickest way to get the decay is the representation as a Neumann series/simple random walk with positive killing rate. See, e.g., Lemma 3 page 10 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4756

Comment: Another idea is complex contour deformation. Try it for $d=1$ first assuming WLOG $x-y>0$, and try to create a positive imaginary part in $k$. For higher $d$ you can iterate by adding the cosine expressions of the previous components of $k$ to the mass $p$. BTW finding exact long distance asymptotics is nontrivial.

Comment: Do you know any reference on this second approach?

Comment: Sounds more or less what I tried to do