# Using Paley-Wiener Theorem to prove the decay of $G(x-y)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis

This question is related to my [previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365164/proving-the-exponential-decay-of-greens-function-for-the-lattice-deltap?noredirect=1#comment921770_365164), where I was looking for some help to prove the decay of the lattice Green function:
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x-y) = \int_{[-\pi,\pi]^{d}}\frac{d^{d}k}{(2\pi)^{d}}\frac{e^{ik\cdot (x-y)}}{\gamma(k)+p} \quad (x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}) \label{1}\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
where $p>0$, $k\cdot (x-y) := k_{1}(x_{1}-y_{1}) +\cdots+k_{d}(x_{d}-y_{d})$ and:
$$\gamma(k) := 2\sum_{j=1}^{d}(1-\cos(k_{j})). $$

As mentioned in the previous question, this decay should be like:
$$G(x-y) \le Ke^{\alpha ||x-y||_{\infty}}$$
where $||x-y||_{\infty} := \max_{i}\{|x_{i}-y_{i}|\}$. As cited in the comments of the previous question, we can address this problem by using contour integrals or representation as a Neumann series. However, in [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103940528) (page 183) the authors propose a very interesting way to prove this result by using the Paley-Wiener Theorem. I'd really like to understand it but they just briefly mention the idea and I'm having trouble working out the details and I'm having trouble making the Paley-Wiener Theorem fit in this context. Shouldn't my function $G$ be an *entire* function of $n$ complex variables given by the Fourier transform of a $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ function? It does not seem the case to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My guess would be that this is the same as what Abdelmalek Abdesselam wrote in his comment to the other question — so strictly speaking not really an application of the Paley–Wiener theorem, but something to some extent similar. (And yes, $G$ is an entire function, once you define it for by the same formula for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^d$.)

Comment: That said, the easiest way to get such a crude upper bound is perhaps as follows: If $p = \cosh \alpha - 2$, then the function $F(x) = \exp(-\alpha\|x\|_\infty)$ is discrete $p$-superharmonic, in the sense that $H(x) := \Delta F(x) - p F(x) \leqslant 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}^d$. Therefore, $F$ is the discrete convolution of $G$ and $-H(x)$ (more precisely: $F + G*H$ is discrete harmonic and goes to zero at infiinity, and hence it is constant zero)). In particular, $F(x) \geqslant (-H(0))G(x)$, that is, $G(x) \leqslant (-H(0))^{-1} F(x)$.

Comment: Oh, this seems a nice approach but I'm not very familiar with some of these objects. If $F(x)$ is $p$-superharmonic does it follow that it is the discrete convolution of $G$ and $-H$? Is this a theorem? Do you have any reference on the precise statement?

Comment: All you need to know is that $(-\Delta + p) G(x) = \delta_0(x)$ (which follows by looking at the Fourier transform, for example). Then we find that $(-\Delta + p) (G * H) = H = (\Delta - p) F)$, and consequently $(-\Delta - p)(F + G*H) = 0$. Now $F + G*H$ goes to zero at infinity (requires a proof!), and — if non-zero — it attains a positive maximum or a negative minimum somewhere. However, if $F(x_0) + G*H(x_0) > 0$ is a maximum, then $\Delta (F + G*H)(x_0) < 0$, and so, in particular, $0 > (\Delta - p)(F + G*H)(x_0) = 0$, a contradiction. Thus, $F + G*H = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Amazing! I will try to work out the details! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I got it! Just one thing: (it is probably easy to see but) why does $F(x) \ge (-H(0))G(x)$?

Comment: That is indeed quite simple: $H(x) \leqslant 0$, and hence $F(x) = (-H) * G(x) = \sum (-H(y)) G(x - y) \ge -H(0) G(x - 0)$.